# opencv cvtColor set/get matrix element

Tags: c++, opencv

```
cv::cvtColor(dst,bwImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

how can I set a specific pixel for example 0,0 value it this bwImage after usign cvtColor?

I usually use:

```
bwImage.at<float>(0,0) = 0;
```

but it now throws an exception.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel
s()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3
) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file C:\Users\gdarmon\Downloads
\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 538
```

Update I have found a work around

```
bwImage.convertTo(bwImage,CV_32F);
bwImage.at<float>(0,0)=0;
```

Comment: Does openCV follow zero indexing? Try `(1,1)`

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Does it have a `push_back` like member function? Assuming your usage is correct, the only reason would that bwImage is NULL. Can you check is it's NULL/empty by the way?

Comment: @Golazo the type of my matrix is uint8 - however I can't do bwImage.at<uint8_t>(0,0)=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already found out, your black and white image does not hold floats, but 8-bit unsigned integers. Besides your workaround you could also do

```
bwImage.at<uint8_t>(0,0) = 0;
```

if you include [stdint.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html). As this is just a typedef for unsigned char, you can also not include the header and do this:

```
bwImage.at<unsigned char>(0,0) = 0;
```

On a side note: the default channel ordering of OpenCV is BGR, so using [CV_RGB2GRAY](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) here would be wrong, if you did not reorder the channels beforehand.